# send data to server when app is in background swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, background, background-service, background-fetch

I need to send the data from coreData to server after 30 minutes even the app is in the background. Currently i'm doing it with timer but timer gets stop working when my application enters background.

Comment: target->capabilities->background modes turn on the switcher, check checkboxes you want. App will resign active in 3 minutes it is an apple standard

Comment: One solution is to send the data when the app is sent to the background and also save a timestamp locally and then if the app is activated again use the timestamp to check if the data should be sent or if it is too soon.

Comment: I can't do that as i'm collecting review data when intenet is not available and storing in my core data. So i need a service which works in background and check after each 30 minutes that if the internet is available and there are reviews which needs to be sync so it simply send them to our server.